# Ubuntu ARM 13.4

Tags: apache2, mono, netbeans, arm, chromebook

I am looking at purchasing a Samsung Chromebook with the integrated 3G (Exynos5 based one). I am trying to find out if the following packages are available in the Ubuntu arm version that can be made to work on the Chromebook:

- LibreOffice4 including Base
- MySQL
- PHP
- Apache Web Server
- Netbeans 7.0x
- Mono
- Monodevelop

I can't seem to find anywhere that tell me if these packages are available for the distro. It would also be great to know if the 3G modem is supported in any form as I would like to work from anywhere.

Does anyone either know the answers or know where I can find the answers?

Answer (score 1):

I'm typing this answer on my ARM Chromebook in Ubuntu (by the Chrubuntu install script from [here](http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/2012/12/so-you-want-chrubuntu-on-external-drive.html)).  I haven't been able to get 3G working in Ubuntu, but [other people have](http://notes.variogr.am/post/39308314835/3g-wireless-in-ubuntu-on-your-arm-chromebook).  It should just work if you try to do a side-by-side install like [Crouton](http://www.howtogeek.com/162120/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-chromebook-with-crouton/).

For the packages, all of those do have a package that you can install.  You can tell by going to a mirror site and checking if they have armhf packages.  However, that doesn't necessarily mean they work.  For example, [Mono doesn't officially support the hard float ABI](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Mono-on-ARM-Chromebook-td4657617.html); the package that you can install is armel and will crash as soon as it does anything with floating point.